# QMap::value return reference to temporary

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I would like to return a const reference to a QMap value. From what I can understand, QMap is special in that if you try to access a key that does not exist, it will create a value with the default constructor and return it. But if I still understand correctly, the reference will be temporary and therefore I get the warning.

I have this piece of code:

```
const T &getSelectionDesc(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    if (!indexes.contains(item))
        indexes.insert(item, T(item->text()));
    return indexes.value(item);
}
```

As you can see, I've already made sure that the key returns something, I create the object the first time it is required and then save it in the QMap for ulterior uses.

Despite that, I still get the warning, what should I change here to correct the behavior?

**Edit:**

Here is how I've defined `indexes`:

```
QMap<QListWidgetItem *, T> indexes;
```

This is the warning I'm getting:

> In instantiation of 'const T& SelectListDialog::getSelectionDesc(QListWidgetItem*) [with T = BackgroundDesc]':
>
> warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>
> return indexes.value(item);

Comment: Show us the exact warning and the declaration of `indexes`?

Comment: @Holt added in OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `QMap::value()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value):

> #### `const T QMap::value(const Key &key, const T &defaultValue = T()) const`

Note that the return type is `const T` and isn't a reference. This means that `return indexes.value(item)` will return a **copy** of the value from the QMap, and not assign a reference. As soon as function scope is exited, the copied object is destroyed -- it is a temporary object. This explains the "reference to temporary" warning you're getting.

In your particular case, use the [subscript operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) instead. The non-const overload returns a reference to type `T`. From the docs:

> #### `T &QMap::operator[](const Key &key)`

You've stated correctly that

> QMap is special in that if you try to access a key that does not exist, it will create a value with the default constructor and return it.

But since you're already checking to make sure that the key `item` exists in your QMap, you guarantee that the key `item` exists. Thus you could (should) change your `return` statement to:

```
return indexes[item];
```

---

Note that for `const QMap`s, the subscript operator would default to the overloaded operator:

> #### `const T QMap::operator[](const Key &key) const`
>
> Same as [value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value)().

This also returns a copy of the value instead of a reference. But as your map is non-const, this overload is not used.

Comment: Alright it is working, thanks a lot, i really thought using value was the way to go there...

Comment: Well, Qt recommends `.value()` in case `key` doesn't exist and you don't wish to create another key-value instance. But in this case, you're already creating the key-value instance even it doesn't exist inside the map yet. So subscript is the way to go. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation